# Python program that wont terminate

Tags: python

I'm running the following code from the command line (python filename.py) and it wont terminate. I've tried the code outside of a procedure and have tried the procedure in an online interpreter, so I don't think it's the the algorithm. What am I doing wrong?

```
    n = raw_input("Enter a number: ")

    def print_multiplication_table(n):

        x = 1

        while x <= n:
            y = 1
            while y <= n:
                z = x * y
                print x, " * ", y, " = ", z
                y += 1
            x += 1

    print_multiplication_table(n)
```

Comment: Please, fix your indentation. I have no idea what the code does/should do if I don't have the proper indentation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should convert the number received from `raw_input` into an integer. Right now it's being compared as a string.

An easy (but probably bad) way to do this:

```
n = int(raw_input("Enter a number: "))
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a problem with the `raw_input` command. I have a similar code myself (guess we're both following the Udacity course). I tried to add the `raw_input` line to my code, and it ended up in an infinite loop too.